# Biber adding doi

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

**main.text**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew, doi=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}

\cite{baffou2014nanoplasmonics}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@article{baffou2014nanoplasmonics,
  title={Nanoplasmonics for chemistry},
  author={Baffou, Guillaume and Quidant, Romain},
  doi={10.1039/C3CS60364D},
  journal={Chemical Society Reviews},
  volume={43},
  number={11},
  pages={3898--3907},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Royal Society of Chemistry}
}
```

[image]

I would like to add a colon `(:)` after the DOI, resulting in the following format: `... DOI: 10.1039/C3CS60364D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  DOI\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
}
```

to your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew, doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  DOI\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}

\cite{baffou2014nanoplasmonics}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The hyperref does not work (the DOI is not clickable).

Comment: I corrected the code.